# Open Excel and Place on top of windows using VBS

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am currently using the below script to open Excel.  The script does as it suppose to but what i need it to do is place excel on top of all windows.  I currently had a script within the excel project to place userforms ontop of all windows but when i get to a certain point within my project it causes excel to crash, so i had pinpointed it to the script within the excel project. here is the script i am using to open excel file:

```
Dim AppExcel 
Set AppExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application") 
AppExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\****\Desktop\ App Tool\App.xlsm"
AppExcel.Visible = False
```

Comment: Other alternative would be minimize everything except Excel?

Comment: could you provide an example to minimize all other programs

Answer (score 2):

Based on comment to minimize every open window and then opening Excel.

```
Set shell = wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Shell.MinimizeAll ''Comment me if you don't want to minimize everything

'Then rest of your code
Dim AppExcel 
Set AppExcel = CreateObject("Excel.application") 
AppExcel.Workbooks.Open "C:\Users\****\Desktop\ App Tool\App.xlsm"
AppExcel.Visible = True

'And in the end Release the Shell object
Set shell = Nothing
```

Comment: You are welcome and pls [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it helped.